# We are are facing issues while trying to drop and recreate a view in DB2

Tags: db2

We are working for an insurance client and are facing issues while trying to drop and recreate a view in DB2. We are using DB2 LUW v9.5.0.3.

Database: DB2 LUW
Version: 9.5.0.3

1. We have a table (TABLE_1) in a schema, SCHEMA_1. There is a view (VIEW_1) built on this table and it resides in the same schema (SCHEMA_1)
2. There is an alias named VIEW_1 residing in schema SCHEMA_2 which is built on the view SCHEMA_1.VIEW_1
3. There are many functions which are residing in SCHEMA_2 and dependent on the alias SCHEMA_2.VIEW_1
4. We need to add a new column in the table SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1 and also need to change the view SCHEMA_1.VIEW_1 to accommodate that

Please let know if there is a way to alter the view by adding the new column without touching any of the dependent objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upgrade to DB2 9.7, which added the `create or replace` functionality was added.